# problem putting an rtf field into visualforce html email template

Tags: visualforce, email-template, visualforce-template

I want to create an email from a template and insert the contents of an rtf field from a record into the email. To this end, I created a visualforce email template (see attached code) [image]My problem is that when the rtf contents of the field are inserted into the body of the email the formatting is lost (see here) [image]and it is converted back into text. rather than minting the formatting (see here)[image] How can I create an email template that will take the contents of an rtf field from a record and insert it into the bey of the email and maintain its formatting? Once I am able to display the formatting correctly (by using the apex code solution below) I still cannot display the image within the RTF field. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
<apex:outputtext value="{!thefield}" escape="false" />
```

This should display the HTML correctly.

Comment: Brilliant, that enables me to get the formatting, BUT it does not show the image embedded, I have updated the question to include the screenshot. Any ideas how I get around that issue of not being able to display the image inline?

Comment: @Bartley: Try using Apex:outputField instead.